# Ringtone reset to default after reboot

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, htc-one-x, ringtone

My ringtone (music stored on the phone storage partition) always reset to default each time I reboot my phone. Does anyone know what is the cause of this? or how can I fix it?

I'm using HTC One X rooted, with stock ROM JB 4.1.1

I have enable phone storage encryption (the 25GB partition)  but I have not not enable app storage encryption (the 6.76GB partition)

Thanks